# If a side in front of $30$ degrees is half another side then prove that the triangle is right angled.

Tags: geometry

Prove that if the segment in front of $30$ degree is $\frac{1}{2}$ another segment the triangle is a right triangle.

In the book it is written that the median is the key to solve these kind of questions but I can't solve it using that any hints?

[image]

Comment: Maybe remember the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) to find the angle opposite to the $2x$ side.

Comment: Construct a congruent triangle reflected across the long leg.  Prove that the two triangles together form and equilateral triangle.  And the median is perpendicular to the base.

Comment: consider an equilateral triangle, draw a line perpendicular line from one of the sides to opposite vertex then you will get it

Comment: @DougM By long leg you mean $2x$?But then it won't be equilateral?

Comment: @dxiv we didn't learn laws of $\sin$ yet.But we have learned laws of $\cos$.

Comment: @TahaAkbari 2x would be the hypotenuse (assuming that it is indeed an equlateral triangle.  When I said long leg, I intended the one that was otherwise unidentified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PICTURE ONE:

[image]

$\angle CAB=30°$ and $AB=2BC$

Assuming $\angle ACB \ne 90°$. We find a point $D$ lying on ray $AC$ such that $\angle BDA=90°$.

Because $\angle CAB=30°$ and $\angle BDA=90°$, $AB=2BD$

However, we have been told that $AB=2BC$.

As a result, $BD=BC$. But $BD$ is perpendicular to $AC$......

CONTRADICTION!

PICTURE TWO:

[image]

$\angle BDA$ is assumed to be $90°$, while $\angle CAB=30°$, so we have $\angle DAB+\angle BDA=240°$.

CONTRADICTION!

Now the proposition is proved.

Comment: Oh, I made such a captial mistake! I'll try to find anthor solution.

Comment: I edited to fix the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let the unknown angle be R. By Sine Rule

$$ \dfrac{\sin R}{2x}=  \dfrac{\sin 30^0}{x} \rightarrow \sin R = 1, R= 90^0. $$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You suppose to prove x=2y, extend your triangle to form another congruent triangle(the brown coloured triangle). Now angle a=60 since sum of the angle of the triangle(black one) should be 180. Since left side triangle is nothing but a mirror image of black triangle, hence b=60 and c=30. Now consider the bigger triangle, all the angles are of equal angles of 60 each, it is an equilateral triangle, therefore all sides are of equal length. So y is nothing but half of x, that is x=2y